# Use a variable as the key in an object literal (to pass to jQuery's animate)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to pass a variable to jQuery's animate method as the property to animate and I'm running into some trouble.  Here's what I've tried:

```
// these first two would really be filled in from an external source:  
var animationAttribute = 'left';
var newTarget = 500;

var animationToPerform = { animationAttribute: newTarget };
$(element[0].selector).stop().animate(animationToPerform, 400, 'linear');
```

It simply doesn't work, with no error.  It works if I hard code the property to animate like this:

```
var newTarget = 500;

var animationToPerform = { 'left': newTarget };
$(element[0].selector).stop().animate(animationToPerform, 400, 'linear');
```

These should be exactly the same thing, as this returns true:

```
'left' === animationAttribute       // (evaluates as true)
```

Please help!

Comment: Note that this problem really has nothing to with `.animate()` - it is a question of how to create an object with property names specified in variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can't use a variable as the key in an object literal. A solution to achieve that is creating an empty object, then using bracket notation to name a new key from a variable:

```
var animationAttribute = 'left';
var newTarget = 500;
var animationParams = {};
animationParams[animationAttribute] = newTarget;

$(element[0].selector).stop().animate(animationParams, 400, 'linear');
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I'll edit my question to reflect the actual issue.  Appreciated!